# How to check if a pixel is black using image.getRGB(x, y)

Tags: java, image, bit-manipulation, pixel

Should I expect the color of the pixel to be black if

`image.getRGB(x, y)` returns 0?

*My assumption:* I would expect 0 because the bit values of each of the values (Red, Green, Blue) would be zero. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: getRGB returns a "packed quad". How is it packed? (This is covered in the documentation.) Does this support/answer/conflict with the hypothesis (that an all black pixel will "be 0")?

Comment: ["Returns the RGB value representing the color in the default sRGB ColorModel. (Bits 24-31 are alpha, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7 are =blue)."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()) With that information, under which circumstances would the assertion of the hypothesis be true/false?

Comment: Wait wouldn't alpha affect it too?

Comment: @Allan Yes, it does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, BufferedImage#getRGB() returns hex number. See this unit test:

```
public class TestRgb {
  @Test
  public void testBlack(){
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(1,1, TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    graphics2D.setPaint(new Color(0,0,0)); //black
    graphics2D.fillRect(0,0,1,1);

    // pass - alpha channel set by default, even on all black pixels
    TestCase.assertTrue(bufferedImage.getRGB(0,0)==0xFF000000);

    // pass - when looking at just the color values (last 24 bits) the value is 0
    TestCase.assertTrue((bufferedImage.getRGB(0,0) & 0x00FFFFFF)==0);

    // fail - see above
    TestCase.assertTrue(bufferedImage.getRGB(0,0)==0);
  }
}
```

Comment: So if i wanted to check it it were white it would be: (image.getRGB(0,0) & 0x00FFFFFF) == 125?

Comment: @Allan No. That bitmask/expression would "select all (and only) the color bits" which are 0xFFFFFF for all-white: 0xFFFFFF == 2^24-1 ~~ 16.7M, which is definitely not 125.

Answer (score 1):

["Returns the RGB value representing the color in the default sRGB ColorModel. (*Bits 24-31 are alpha*, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7 are =blue)."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB())

That is, the packing (in hex locations) is as follows, where each component can have a value of 0 (0x00) .. 255 (0xFF).

```
AARRGGBB
```

Thus, the final value is *not only* dependent upon RGB, when all *color* components are zero:

```
AA000000
```

In fact, *AA will be 0xFF ("100% opaque") by default* unless it has explicitly been set to a different value in a buffer / model that supports an alpha channel.